# Problem 'module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'plot_filterz'

Tags: python, math, plot, filter, signal-processing

I tried to fix this code many times, yet it still keep the same problem. Here the error code of Python Language that I received:

```
#----------------------------------------------------
#FIR filter

n=100 #Design filter
b=signal.firwin(n, cutoff= 0.2, window = "hamming")
#Plot properties
plt .plot_filterz(b)

x = np.sin(np . linspace(0,500,1024))+0.5*np. cos(np. linspace(0,750,1024))+ np.random.randn(1024)*0.2 +0.2*np. cos(np . linspace(0, 10000, 1024))
xfiltered = signal.lfilter(b, 1, x) 

plt.plot(x[:200], label = "Original signal")
plt.plot(xfiltered[:200], "--k", label = "Filtered signal")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

I could not figure on why I keep getting 'module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'plot_filterz' object has no attribute 'firwin'? Here's my full code(edited): https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VPjlRgssIMfPp4xEP5wV3vG0ROLxXoos4oMMTjMoyVs/edit

Comment: I guess you want to call firwing from module signal. You must import signal first: `from sicpy import signal`. Also, do not call you array "signal" as it conflicts with the module name. Rename it at top of your (full) code.

Comment: From your terminal: `pip install scipy` (or `conda install scipy` if using Anaconda).  Then in your code: `from scipy import signal` as @RicVillalba mentioned.

Comment: done but i got another error which is this one: module 'matplotlib.pyplot' has no attribute 'plot_filterz'

Comment: Here's my updated code: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1VPjlRgssIMfPp4xEP5wV3vG0ROLxXoos4oMMTjMoyVs/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code with a sample .wav file and observed that there were many bugs in your code. I have refactored your code and these are plots that are now generated from the refactored code.

Highlights of bugs:

- plot_filterz was custom function, but was wrongly called as
  plt.plot_filterz
- np.fromstring expects a string but bytes was provided
- numpy does not    have a freqz function, scipy.signal has a freqz function
- numpy does not have a function called impulse np.impulse
- numpy.arctan2 function was called with single argument, it expects two arguments

[image: filter properties]

[image: orignal vs filtered signal]

Refactored code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import wave
from scipy import signal

def plot_freqz(c, a=1):
    w, h = signal.freqz(c, a)
    h_dB = 20 * np.log10(abs(h))
    plt.plot(w / np.pi, h_dB)
    plt.ylim([max(min(h_dB), -100), 5])
    plt.ylabel('Magnitude (db)')
    plt.xlabel(r'Normalized Frequency (x$\pi$rad/sample)')
    plt.title(r'Amplitude response')


def plot_phasez(c, a=1):
    w, h = signal.freqz(c, a)
    h_Phase = np.unwrap(np.arctan(np.imag(h)))
    plt.plot(w / np.pi, h_Phase)
    plt.ylabel('Phase(radians)')
    plt.xlabel(r'Normalized Frequency (x$\pi$rad/sample)')
    plt.title(r'Phase response')


def plot_impz(c, a=1):
    if type(a) == int:  # FIR
        factor = 10000  # using this factor to speed up the plotting. change as per your need
        l = int(len(c) / factor)

    else:  # IIR
        l = 100
    impulse = np.repeat(0., l)
    impulse[0] = 1
    x = np.linspace(0, 1, l)
    response = signal.lfilter(c, a, impulse)

    plt.stem(x, response, linefmt='b-', basefmt='b-', markerfmt='bo')
    plt.ylabel('Amplitude')
    plt.xlabel(r'n(samples)')
    plt.title(r'Impulse response')


def plot_stepz(c, a=1):
    if type(a) == int:  # FIR
        factor = 10000 # using this factor to speed up the plotting. change as per your need
        l = int(len(c)/factor)

    else:  # IIR
        l = 100
    impulse = np.repeat(0., l)
    impulse[0] = 1
    x = np.arange(0, l)
    response = signal.lfilter(c, a, impulse)
    plt.plot(x, np.cumsum(response))
    plt.ylabel(' Amplitude')
    plt.xlabel(r'n(samples)')
    plt.title(r'Step response')


def plot_filterz(c, a=1):
    print('plotting freqz plot')
    plt.subplot(221)
    plot_freqz(c, a)
    print('plotting phasez plot')
    plt.subplot(222)
    plot_phasez(c, a)
    print('plotting impz plot')
    plt.subplot(223)
    plot_impz(c, a)
    print('plotting stepz plot')
    plt.subplot(224)
    plot_stepz(c, a)
    plt.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.5, wspace=0.3)
    plt.savefig('filter_properties.png')
    plt.show()
    print('done plotting properties')


def ma(x, n=5):
    b = np.ones(n) / n
    xf = signal.lfilter(b, 1, x)
    return xf


# ----------------------------------------------------
# FIR filter
if __name__ == '__main__':
    spf = wave.open('BabyElephantWalk60.wav', 'r') #sample .wav file, replace with your .wav file

    # Extract Original Audio from Wav File
    c = spf.readframes(-1)
    # c = np.fromstring(c, np.int16)

    c= np.frombuffer(c, dtype=np.int16)
    n = 100  # Design filter
    b = signal.firwin(n, cutoff=0.2, window="hamming")
    # Plot properties
    plot_filterz(c)

    x = np.sin(np.linspace(0, 500, 1024)) + 0.5 * np.cos(np.linspace(0, 750, 1024)) + np.random.randn(
        1024) * 0.2 + 0.2 * np.cos(np.linspace(0, 10000, 1024))
    print('calculating lfilter of x')
    xfiltered = signal.lfilter(b, 1, x)

    print('plotting original signal and filtered signal')
    plt.title('Original signal v/s filtered signal')
    plt.plot(x[:200], label="Original signal")
    plt.plot(xfiltered[:200], "--k", label="Filtered signal")
    plt.legend()
    plt.savefig('orignal_vs_filtered_signal.png')
    plt.show()
```